# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client posting data and file to a web api

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a form which I am using to post both data and file to a `web` `api` `endpoint`. One of the data field is `RichTextField` using `summernote` plugin.

The `angularjs` script posting to the `endpoint` looks like this:

```
$scope.transaction = {};
var files = $scope.myFile;
var fd = new FormData();

angular.forEach(files, function (value, key) {
    fd.append("file" + key, value[0]);
});

fd.append("fileContent", JSON.stringify({ fileContent: $scope.transaction }));

dataService.uploadFile(baseAddress + "/Generate", fd)
.success(function (data) {}).error(function (data) {  });
```

The endpoint accepting the request looks like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Generate()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

           var contentResult = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;                
           var key = contentResult.AllKeys[0];
           var val = contentResult.GetValues(key)[0];
```

At this point `var val = contentResult.GetValues(key)[0];` I am getting this error message:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
```

I have tried this:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost, System.Web.Mvc.ValidateInput(false)]
```

also

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Comment: try adding to your web.config 

    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />

Comment: @J.Loscos it did not work

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error, but on my machine <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> does the trick. I have no idea why it's not working for you

Comment: What versions of IIS, .NET and ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: IIS express, .Net 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow html tags since summernote data contains them. To do this you need to add [AllowHtmlAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) to your method.

You might need to do some tinkering since it allows to do xss and other stuff pretty easily.

Comment: AllowHtml is a property attribute to be used on the model. So he would need to add a model in his controller action parameter

Comment: @J.Loscos ahh, of course you are right. It's been a while since i've used it.

Comment: @TestzWCh I know about AllowHtmlAttribute. The point where the error occured is not at the point of casting to a model.